# JsonArrayRequest cannot parse JSONArray from my API to Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, xml

I have already researched everything about parsing JSON data using Volley library and it seems like the API cannot really parse the data into my Android app. For sure, I have tried using StringRequest, JsonObjectRequest, and JsonArrayRequest and everything doesn't work at all.

Btw, this is the API data I want to parse to my Android App

```
[
   {"id":1,
    "name":"Jus Mangga",
    "seller":{
              "id":1,
              "name":"Sulton",
              "email":"sulton@gmail.com",
              "phoneNumber":"0822",
              "location":{ "province":"Banten","description":"Pusat","city":"Tangerang"}
             },
    "price":20000,
    "category":"Beverages"
   },
   {"id":2,
    "name":"Pastry",
    "seller":{
              "id":1,
              "name":"Sulton",
              "email":"sulton@gmail.com",
              "phoneNumber":"0822",
              "location":{"province":"Banten","description":"Pusat","city":"Tangerang"}
             },
   "price":60000,
   "category":"Bakery"
   }
]
```

I have recognized this as JSONArray so I directly implement Volley using JsonArrayRequest and it doesn't work.

Below is all code regarding the app:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.json_parsing">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_parse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        android:text="Parse" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.json_parsing;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView text_view;
    private Button button_parse;
    private String food_name;
    private int food_price;
    private String food_category;
    private static final String SERVER_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/food/listFood";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        button_parse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_parse);

        button_parse.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            json_data_parser();
        });

    }

    public void json_data_parser() {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
                0,
                SERVER_URL,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        try {
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                food_name = response.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                                food_price = response.getJSONObject(i).getInt("price");
                                food_category = response.getJSONObject(i).getString("category");

                                text_view.append("\n");
                                text_view.append("Food name: " + food_name + "\n");
                                text_view.append("Food price: " + food_price + "\n");
                                text_view.append("Food category: " + food_category + "\n\n");
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                error -> Log.d("Error", "Error occurred", error));
        queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

    }

}
```

After I run the code, the JSON data seems not appear on the activity

[JSON data parse not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8cYT.png)

The funny thing, when I Try to use hard-coded JSONArray using String, the parse process is successful. Below is the code I use for hard-coded JSONArray

```
button_parse.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            final String jsonObject = "[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Jus Mangga\",\"seller\":{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Sulton\",\"email\":\"sulton@gmail.com\",\"phoneNumber\":\"0822\",\"location\":{\"province\":\"Banten\",\"description\":\"Pusat\",\"city\":\"Tangerang\"}},\"price\":20000,\"category\":\"Beverages\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Pastry\",\"seller\":{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Sulton\",\"email\":\"sulton@gmail.com\",\"phoneNumber\":\"0822\",\"location\":{\"province\":\"Banten\",\"description\":\"Pusat\",\"city\":\"Tangerang\"}},\"price\":60000,\"category\":\"Bakery\"}]";
            try {
                JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(jsonObject);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject objectJSON = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(i);
                    food_name = objectJSON.getString("name");
                    food_price = objectJSON.getInt("price");
                    food_category = objectJSON.getString("category");

                    text_view.append("\n");
                    text_view.append("Food name: " + food_name + "\n");
                    text_view.append("Food price: " + food_price + "\n");
                    text_view.append("Food category: " + food_category + "\n\n");

                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        });
```

[Hard-coded JSON data is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93tvQ.png)

> From here, I conclude that there is something wrong with my API **OR** maybe the process of API request it self?

**NOTE:** This is my final project and I hope somebody can really help get through this.

**EDIT**

I also have already tried using GSON. This is because I think my API data is like String-like-JSONArray and It doesn't work as well. I have reference for this is from here

https://medium.com/@akshatjindal215/fetching-data-via-a-simple-api-request-with-volley-a3711efefc7e

Comment: is the response have the values in it?

Comment: @Erwin I debug and put breakpoints to jsonArrayRequest() and food_name, food_price and food_category is all null. Also, it likes skip directly to the errorListener when I try to step Into the code

Comment: have u try sending the request using postman?

Comment: Side note: The JSON shown at the beginning of your question is not valid: `"location:{...`. Should be `"location":{...`.

Comment: @Erwin Yeah I have tried and the backend is seems good. There is no problem in it. I open the API using GET and it all show up. The only problem is when I want to parse to my Android and The API seems doesn't work

Comment: @andrewjames Sry It just maybe typo or I not really detail when I write my problem at first. I will edit it. Thank u

Comment: what is the error in the errorListener? what is the response code?

Comment: @Erwin no. errorListener is just fine. I mean fine there is no something error trace while I am debugging.

Comment: "Also, it likes skip directly to the errorListener when I try to step Into the code " I think there's should be an error

Comment: @Erwin so the error is in the Response.Listener right ? If yes, where should I start to begin fixing the bug? From the top level which is the onResponse method, It seems all my code is looking good (as I follow all the tutorial on the Internet). Maybe I have to fix from the invoked method by onResponse? (which means I have to deep step into the code) ?

Comment: u said it skip to errorListener, so it skip to this line? -> error -> Log.d("Error", "Error occurred", error)); just check the error variable what's in there, may be you could also implement Response.ErrorListener() like in here -> https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request

Comment: @Erwin It says "java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to 10.0.2.2 not permitted"

Comment: @Erwin I have fixed my problem :). Btw thank you for your solution to see the error message in errorListener. Thank u very much